# Android Service for recording on background

Tags: android, service

I need to implement a recording service on android. i have been investing a lot of time reading about services, working on the backgroud in android and yet i still havent figured it out yet. this is what i have done so far :

1. i started by implementing a service that creates and maintains an AudioRecord instance on its onCreate
2. i subclassed Application and started the service from application's onCreate
3. i bind to that service from MainActivity on onResume and unbind on onPause
4. the service's onBind works like LocalService sample from Android SDK samples, meanning that i return binder that holds the service instance and have a getter for it
5. the service API lets its clients start and pause the AudioRecord it maintains

Now what i expcted was that the service's onCreate would be called only once for the time the application started it, but surprisingly, it seems like sometimes when i bind to that service the service restarts (onCreate and onStartCommand is called)!

this behaviour is very bad for me as when the user starts the record from the MainActivity
(using the service instance API)and then presses home and then goes back to my app again,  the service's onCreate is being invoked again and the AudioRecorder is being recreated!

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125846/891814).

a note about Dave's answer, I do need to call startService as the recording should be able to be continued while application is on the background, but if i use bindService on some activity's onCreate then i would have to unbind the connection perhaps on its onDestroy, which would make the service stop running (if this activity was the only one binding to it.

I could always bind to the service from the application onCreate, but then when will i unbind to it? even if i unbind it only when user pressed back on the main activity, but this might cause a leak.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `startService` at all. `bindService` will create the `Service` when necessary. Those two methods are for two different use cases.

Response to comment:

Your post presented no use case for which `startService` needed to be called. You asked why `onCreate` was called twice. It is called twice because it is created twice. Perhaps you are not returning `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand`, or perhaps you are stopping it in your code somewhere. There's no code, so no one here can possibly know. But if `onCreate` is called twice, to be sure it needs to be created twice. From your description, the two calls most likely correspond to the calls to `startService` and `bindService`. My answer is as correct as can be expected with the information provided, but thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I do need to call start service for that it would be ready for binding beforehand also the service should run even if it has no clients bounded to it, because activities may bind to the recording service and the recording should continue while the activity is long gone

Comment: @OfekRon: seems to me that Dave's answer is correct.  if your Service re-created - then it most be that it destroyed. it's possible that the entire process destroy when you hit the home button since your app holds too much memory..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create recording app like [Background Video Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoeticdot.privatevideorecorder)

then you need to use IntentService instead of Service because IntentService runs in background thread.

```
public class RecorderService extends Service implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private Camera camera = null;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;
    private String fileName = "";
    private StopServiceBroadcast stopServiceBroadcast;
    private String endRecordingDate;
    private String endRecordingTime;
    private SettingsModel settingsModel;
    private Handler enableViewsHandler;
    private Runnable runnable;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        settingsModel = SettingsModel.findById(SettingsModel.class, 1L);
        setupSurfaceViewForRecording();
    }

    private void setupSurfaceViewForRecording() {

        int LAYOUT_FLAG;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
        }

        // Create new SurfaceView, set its size to 1x1, move it to the top left corner and set this service as a callback
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                1, 1,
//                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
//                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    private void registerBroadcastToStopRec() {
        stopServiceBroadcast = new StopServiceBroadcast();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("stop_recording_action");
        registerReceiver(stopServiceBroadcast, filter);
    }

    // Method called right after Surface created (initializing and starting MediaRecorder)
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        setupCameraSide();

//        if (settingsModel.getCameraSide().equalsIgnoreCase("front") && !getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
//            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.front_camera_is_not_available_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            if (SharedPreferenceUtility.getInstance().getBooleanPreference(PreferenceKeys.IS_APP_RUNNING))
//                fabStartStopRec.setEnabled(true);
//            this.stopSelf();
//            return;
//        } else if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
//            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.back_camera_is_not_available_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            if (SharedPreferenceUtility.getInstance().getBooleanPreference(PreferenceKeys.IS_APP_RUNNING))
//                fabStartStopRec.setEnabled(true);
//            this.stopSelf();
//            return;
//        }

        //______ check if camera is not available ___________
        if (camera == null) {
            if (settingsModel.getCameraSide().equals("front"))
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.front_camera_is_not_available_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.back_camera_is_not_available_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (SharedPreferenceUtility.getPreference(this, PreferenceKeys.IS_APP_RUNNING, true))
                fabStartStopRec.setEnabled(true);
            this.stopSelf();
            return;
        }

        notificationToShowRecordingStarted();

        setupCameraParametersForRecording();
        setupCameraOrientation();
        setupAutoStopRecordingFactors();
        setupRingingAndVibrationOnStartRec();


        try {
            //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        camera.startPreview();
        camera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

        setupVideoQuality();
        setupVideoStorage();
        startRecording();
    }

    private void setupRingingAndVibrationOnStartRec() {
        if (settingsModel.isRingsOnRecStarts()) {
            Uri ringTuneUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.rec_start_sound);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), ringTuneUri);
            r.play();
        } else {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            if (info.canDisableShutterSound) {
                camera.enableShutterSound(false);
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                // to mute shutter sound of camera
                final AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
                mgr.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (!mgr.isStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM))
                        mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
                }

            } else {

            }
        }

        if (settingsModel.isVibrateOnRecStarts()) {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            } else
                v.vibrate(500);
        }
    }

    private void setupVideoQuality() {

        if (settingsModel.getCameraSide().equals("front")) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
            else
                mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P/*settingsModel.getVideoQuality()*/));/*hot fix 1*/
        } else
            mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(settingsModel.getVideoQuality()));

//        if (settingsModel.getCameraSide().equals("front") &&
//                (settingsModel.getVideoQuality() == CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH || settingsModel.getVideoQuality() == CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P)) {
//            mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));
//        } else
//            mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(settingsModel.getVideoQuality()));
    }

    private int getVideoQualityWRTCameraCapacity(int videoQuality) {
        switch (videoQuality) {
            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_CIF:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_CIF;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QCIF:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QCIF;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_480P:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_480P;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QCIF:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QCIF;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QVGA:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_QVGA;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_CIF:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_CIF;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_LOW:
                return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_LOW;

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_480P:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_480P;
                }

            case CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_LOW:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_LOW;
                }
        }

        return CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH;
    }

    private void setupAutoStopRecordingFactors() {

        if (settingsModel.isRecordingScheduled() && isValidTime(settingsModel.getWakeUpTimeForTimer())) {
            mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(settingsModel.getScheduleRecordingTimeDuration() * 60 * 1000);

            if (settingsModel.isMaxFileSize())
                mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(settingsModel.getMaxFileSizeLimit() * 1024 * 1024);
        } else {
            if (settingsModel.isLimitRecordingTime())
                mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(settingsModel.getRecordingTimeLimit() * 60 * 1000);

            if (settingsModel.isMaxFileSize())
                mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(settingsModel.getMaxFileSizeLimit() * 1024 * 1024);
        }

        mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
                if (i == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                    stopSelf();
                } else if (i == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) {
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isValidTime(long wakeUpTimeInMillis) {
        Calendar smsTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        smsTime.setTimeInMillis(wakeUpTimeInMillis);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (now.get(Calendar.DATE) == smsTime.get(Calendar.DATE)) {
            if (now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == smsTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) {
                if (now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == smsTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void setupCameraOrientation() {

        if (settingsModel.getCameraSide().equals("front")) {
            if (settingsModel.getCameraOrientation().equals("auto") || settingsModel.getCameraOrientation().equals("portrait")) {
                mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
            } else
                mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(0);
        } else {
            if (settingsModel.getCameraOrientation().equals("auto") || settingsModel.getCameraOrientation().equals("portrait")) {
                mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            } else
                mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(180);
        }
    }

    private void setupCameraParametersForRecording() {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> ss = parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes();
        Log.d("------ 0", ss.get(0).width + "   " + ss.get(0).height);
        Log.d("------ last", ss.get(ss.size() - 1).width + "   " + ss.get(ss.size() - 1).height);
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes();
        for (Camera.Size s : sizes)
            Log.d("----", String.valueOf(s.width) + " * " + String.valueOf(s.height));

        if (settingsModel.isFlashlightWhileRec() && !settingsModel.getCameraSide().equalsIgnoreCase("front"))
            parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

        //_______ setup zoom factor ___________
        if (settingsModel.isZoomEnabled()) {
            if (parameters.isZoomSupported()) {
                if (settingsModel.getZoomInValue() >= 0 && settingsModel.getZoomInValue() <= parameters.getMaxZoom()) {
                    parameters.setZoom(settingsModel.getZoomInValue());
                }
            }
        }

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    private void setupCameraSide() {
        if (settingsModel.getCameraSide().equals("front"))
            camera = openFrontFacingCamera();
        else
            camera = Camera.open();
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            saveRecStartingTime();
            if (SharedPreferenceUtility.getPreference(this, PreferenceKeys.IS_APP_RUNNING, false))
                updateViewsOnStartRec();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void updateViewsOnStartRec() {
        sflStartStopRecProgress.stopShimmerAnimation();

        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.setText("00:00:00");
        chronometer.start();

        fabStartStopRec.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stop_icon), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_icon));
        fabStartStopRec.showProgress(true);
        fabStartStopRec.setIndeterminate(true);

        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fabStartStopRec.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        enableViewsHandler = new Handler();
        enableViewsHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }

    private void saveRecStartingTime() {
        SharedPreferenceUtility.setPreference(this, PreferenceKeys.IS_RECORDING, true);
        SharedPreferenceUtility.setPreference(this, PreferenceKeys.REC_STARTING_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    private void setupVideoStorage() {

        //___________ creating new directory __________
        File f = new File(settingsModel.getStoragePath(), settingsModel.getStorageFolderName());
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }

        if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {

            try {
                fileName = settingsModel.getStoragePath() + "/" + settingsModel.getStorageFolderName() + "/" +
                        DateFormat.format(settingsModel.getFileNameFormat(), new Date().getTime()) + ".mp4";
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.you_dont_have_enough_space_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
    }

    // Stop recording and remove SurfaceView
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        updateViewsOnStopRec();
        updateSqlite();

        //_________ if camera was not available __________
        if (camera != null && mediaRecorder != null) {
            final File file = new File(fileName);
            saveAndScanFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.reset();
            mediaRecorder.release();

            camera.lock();
            camera.release();

            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            if (info.canDisableShutterSound) {
                camera.enableShutterSound(true);
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                // to mute shutter sound of camera
                final AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
                mgr.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (mgr.isStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC))
                        mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
                }

            } else {

            }


            /*if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                // to unmute shutter sound of camera
                AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
            } else {
                Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                if (info.canDisableShutterSound) {
                    camera.enableShutterSound(true);
                }
            }*/

            windowManager.removeView(surfaceView);

            if (settingsModel.isShowNotificationOnRecStarts())
                unregisterReceiver(stopServiceBroadcast);

            if (settingsModel.isShowNotificationOnRecStops()) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        sendRecordedVideoNotification(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }

            setupRiningAndVIberationOnStopRec();
            if (SharedPreferenceUtility.getPreference(this, PreferenceKeys.IS_APP_RUNNING, false) && runnable != null)
                enableViewsHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }

    private void setupRiningAndVIberationOnStopRec() {
        if (settingsModel.isRingsOnRecStops()) {
            Uri ringTuneUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.rec_end_sound);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), ringTuneUri);
            r.play();
        }
        if (settingsModel.isVibrateOnRecStops()) {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(500, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            } else
                v.vibrate(500);
        }
    }

    private void updateViewsOnStopRec() {
        if (SharedPreferenceUtility.getPreference(this, PreferenceKeys.IS_APP_RUNNING, false)) {
            if (chronometer != null)
                chronometer.stop();

            fabStartStopRec.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_icon), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stop_icon));
            fabStartStopRec.showProgress(false);
            fabStartStopRec.setIndeterminate(false);

            if (sflStartStopRecProgress.isAnimationStarted())
                sflStartStopRecProgress.stopShimmerAnimation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void showCustomNotification(String fileName, String videoPath) {
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.single_expanded_notification_layout);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_app_name, "Private Video Recorder");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_video_name, fileName);
        contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.iv_video_image, getVideoThumbnail(videoPath));

        Intent playVideoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoPath));
        playVideoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoPath), "video/mp4");
        PendingIntent playVideoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, playVideoIntent, 0);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_play_video, playVideoPendingIntent);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_cancel, PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0, null));

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setCustomBigContentView(contentView);

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }

    private void notificationToShowRecordingStarted() {
        registerBroadcastToStopRec();

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("stop_recording_action");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            /*if (settingsModel.isShowNotificationOnRecStarts() || settingsModel.isRecordingScheduled() || !SharedPreferenceUtility.getPreference(this, PreferenceKeys.IS_APP_RUNNING, false)) {*/
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, createNotificationChannel());
            notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.recording_running_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.private_video_recorder))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.click_to_stop_recording))
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .build();

            int REC_STARTS_NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;
            startForeground(REC_STARTS_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
            /*}*/
        } else {
            if (settingsModel.isShowNotificationOnRecStarts()) {
                notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setSound(null)
                        .setVibrate(null)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.private_video_recorder))
                        .setContentText(getString(R.string.click_to_stop_recording))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.recording_running_icon)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .build();

                int REC_STARTS_NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;
                startForeground(REC_STARTS_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
            }
        }

//        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
//        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        /*int REC_STARTS_NOTIFICATION_ID = 123;
        startForeground(REC_STARTS_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);*/
    }




    private Camera openFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraCount = 0;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                try {
                    camera = Camera.open(camIdx);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.camera_failed_to_open_) + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        return camera;
    }

    private void updateSqlite() {
        SettingsModel settingsModel = SettingsModel.findById(SettingsModel.class, 1L);
        settingsModel.setRecordingScheduled(false);
        settingsModel.save();

        SharedPreferenceUtility.setPreference(this, PreferenceKeys.IS_RECORDING, false);
    }

}
```